# Studying the convergence of a series with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find for which $x, x\in \mathbb{R}$ the series converges.  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+(-3)^n}{\sqrt{n}}(2x)^n$$

I know this is an alternating series and if $x=0$ it's trivial but I don't know how to continue so please can you help me and give some hints please? Thank you.

Update

So if I apply the ratio test I have

$$\lim_{n→∞}\left|\frac{n+1+(-3)^{n+1}}{n+(-3)^{n}}\right||2x| $$ now how can I prove $\lim_{n→∞}\left|\frac{n+1+(-3)^{n+1}}{n+(-3)^{n}}\right|=3 $ ?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the ratio test or the root test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the ratio test that your series converges if $\lvert x\rvert<\frac16$ and diverges if $\lvert x\rvert>\frac16$.

If $x=\frac16$, your series becomse $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+(-3)^n}{\sqrt n}\frac1{3^n}$, which converges (it's the sum of two convergent series). And if $x=-\frac16$, your series becomse $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+(-3)^n}{\sqrt n}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}$, which diverges (it's the sum of a convergent series with a divergent one).

Comment: So if I apply the ratio test I have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \left|\frac{n+1+(-3)^{n+1}}{n+(-3)^n}\right ||2x|$ and how can I prove that limit is $3|2x|$?

Comment: @JhonKnows, the terms $3^n$ grow much larger than $n$ as $n \to \infty$.